Does the Dual Wielding Sphere from Spheres of Power allow a humanoid to attack twice a round with a slam attack?
Does Spheres of Power Dual Wielding Sphere allow a humanoid to attack twice a round with a slam attack?

What work have you done to investigate this yourself? Further details explaining what you’ve looked at and what specifically about that is confusing would improve this question and help others give you a better answer.

Just the base knowledge of Mutant Template stating for choosing Slam mutations stating"Slam (Ex)
The mutant gains a slam attack for each arm or forelimb. These attacks deal damage based on the mutant’s size. If the mutant already has a slam attack, its slam damage improves by one size category."

@JhyarelleSilver Hey, just noticed something, did you mean spheres of power or spheres of might? because you tagged it as powers but the dual wielding comes from might, and those are different rules systems

Despite the question lacking details, the answer is no.
The reason for this is because you asked about a slam attack, which is a natural attack and NOT a weapon attack. Natural attacks do not function like weapon attacks.

You do not receive additional natural attacks for a high base attack bonus. Instead, you receive additional attack rolls for multiple limb and body parts capable of making the attack (as noted by the race or ability that grants the attacks)

And since the Dual Attack from the Dual Wielding Sphere is worded like two weapon fighting, which does not work with natural attacks because it relies on weapons, and a slam attack isn't held in a limb/hand.

I see, and here I thought Slam Attacks are like Unarmed Strike are treated a light or 1 handed weapons.

@JhyarelleSilver Is it because of monks and monks blurring that line?

Yes, I'd like to like able to attack twice a round as a standard action, keep the option of a move action with little feat chains as possible.

@JhyarelleSilver Attack with what? Spells, weapons, natural attacks, a combination of those?

Weapon or unarmed, I just started to play around with Spheres of Power

@JhyarelleSilver Well, its been a few years but a dm of mine did a theory build using spheres of power which gave a staggering number of attacks, it built on using arm cannons and getting as many arms as possible. I could try to see if I could remember how it was done

@JhyarelleSilver Sorry, I cant remember the build or piece it together, the dm doesnt remember, and the chat it happened in was deleted

Fering, thanks for trying
